# SQLAlchemy ForeignKey and item creation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to better understand SQL Alchemy to start using this ORM with Flask. I have two SQL tables. There is a many - one relationship between the two tables. I am trying to find a way by using SQL Alchemy to add an entry to the child table by using a foreing key but using a different field in the parent table.

```
│   .dockerignore
│   .env
│   .env-template
│   .gitignore
│   docker-compose.yml
│   Dockerfile
│   manage.py
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
├───app
│   │   config.py
│   │   routes.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───sites
│   │       controller.py
│   │       interface.py
│   │       model.py
│   │       schema.py
│   │       service.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   └───devices
│           controller.py
│           interface.py
│           model.py
│           schema.py
│           service.py
│           __init__.py
├───config
│       gunicorn.py
```

`app --> sites --> model.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String
from app import db  # noqa
from .interface import SiteInterface


class Site(db.Model):  # type: ignore
    """Site"""

    __tablename__ = "sites"

    site_db_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    dc_site_id = Column(Integer(), unique=True)
    dc_name = Column(String(100))
```

`app --> sites --> interface.py`

```
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict


class SiteInterface(TypedDict, total=False):
    site_id: int
    dc_site_id: int
    dc_name: str
```

`app --> sites --> schema.py`

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema


class SiteSchema(Schema):
    """Site schema"""

    siteId = fields.Number(attribute="site_db_id")
    dcsiteId = fields.Number(attribute="dc_site_id")
    dcname = fields.String(attribute="dc_name")
```

`app --> devices --> model.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from app import db  # noqa
from .interface import DeviceInterface

class Device(db.Model):  # type: ignore
    """Device"""

    __tablename__ = "devices"

    device_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    hostname = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    ip = Column(String(15), unique=True)
    site_db_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sites.site_db_id'))
    sites = relationship("Site")
```

`app --> devices --> interface.py`

```
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict


class DeviceInterface(TypedDict, total=False):
    deviceId: int
    hostname: str
    ip: str
    sitedbId: int
```

`app --> devices --> schema.py`

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema


class DeviceSchema(Schema):
    """Device schema"""

    deviceId = fields.Number(attribute="device_id")
    hostname = fields.String(attribute="hostname")
    ip = fields.String(attribute="ip")
    sitedbId = fields.Number(attribute="site_db_id")
```

I need help to find the way to be able to add a new Device and specify the `site_db_id` using the `dc_site_id`

Something like this.

```
    @staticmethod
    def create(new_attrs: DeviceInterface) -> Device:
        new_device = Device(
            hostname=new_attrs["hostname"], ip=new_attrs["ip"],
            site_db_id=new_attrs["????"] *** select site_db_id FROM sites where dc_site_id=site_db_id ****
        )

        db.session.add(new_device)
        db.session.commit()

        return new_device
```

Thank you in advance for helping!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement, you can use a two step approach: First select the Site using dc_site_id, then create the new Device with the Site found. Code could look for example like:

```
dc_site_id = new_attrs["dc_site_id "]
sitefound = Site.query.filter_by(dc_site_id = dc_site_id ).first_or_404()
new_device = Device(...,...., relatedsite = sitefound)
```

where *relatedsite* is the backref that you add in the Site class for your relationship.

```
devices= db.relationship('Device', backref='relatedsite', lazy=True)
```

This was this approach for one to many relationships that I found initially in the flask-sqlalchemy [manual](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/):

```
class Person(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
  addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy=True)

class Address(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
  person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), 
     nullable=False)
```

Comment: The relationship is many devices to one site. I think I have to keep the relationship I already created. I try your way and I loose the relationship. Maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: My flask-sqlalchemy code samples work with the foreign key in the "there are many" class and the relationship as described on the "one" class. In have added the link to the manual that I used in the answer.

Comment: My model don't include dc_site_id but only the foreing key to site_db_id. Also the schema and the interface. I add more code for the context.

Comment: Ok I find a way to use your solution. Thx a lot!!